# How to change background color of nth-last-child(2) when :last-child is style is color: yellow

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins, cascading

I need when last child's color is yellow need to add :nth-last-child(2) as **RED** background color without JavaScript

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr th[style='color: yellow;']:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th class="last" style="color: yellow;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is impossible to do with CSS currently, given the way that it is parsed in browsers. You can only go forward down the document tree, you can't go back up the DOM based on any criteria

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector